# transfer string values with an specific word to other columns in a data frame pandas,python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following  problem with this example data based in a bigger data with 420 rows.
The columns are "`m2`", "`rooms`" , and "`toilets`". I'm using pandas and python.

[image]

I would like to transfer the strings that contain the words '`room`','`rooms`','`toilet`' and '`toilets`' from the column '`m2`' and the column '`rooms`' to their corresponding columns, in this case '`rooms`' and '`toilets`'. I have problems trying to transfer this values and keeping the  row of this information into  the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition using str.contains

```
cond1=df.rooms.str.contains('toilet')
cond2=df.m2.str.contains('room')
cond3=df.m2.str.contains('toilet')
```

Apply `np.where(if condition, yes, else-alternative)`

```
 df['toilets']=np.where(cond1,df.rooms,df.toilets)
df['rooms']=np.where(cond2,df.m2,df.rooms)
df['toilets']=np.where(cond3,df.m2,df.toilets)
```

[image]